# Do upgraded rooms require more power than non-upgraded rooms?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Can I get away with building less power infrastructure if I go with a smaller number of heavily-upgraded rooms vs a larger number of non-upgraded rooms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upgraded rooms require more power. ([Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nai09D_aM2syl3iPP5hkveDcOUwhsoUDR6s1lwC0e8c/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true#))

However, you will indirectly use less power by using a smaller number of heavily-upgraded rooms, as you will need fewer dwellers to man them (requiring less food/water -> requiring fewer food/water rooms -> using less power).